# Getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions even with Multidex enabled

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase

I have an Android application using Firebase and Google Maps. I launched the application on a real device which is on JellyBean. I have enabled multidex and tried a lot of other solutions, but I still can't fix the error.

Here is my code. gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.codehacker.pocketambulance"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    generatedDensities = []
    multiDexEnabled true
}

dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}

aaptOptions {
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
}

buildTypes 
{
   release 
   {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
   }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I also used `Multidex.install(this);` in my main activity.java

```
 package com.codehacker.pocketambulance;

 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.multidex.MultiDex;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 import com.firebase.ui.auth.AuthUI;
 import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
 private static final int RC_SIGN_IN=0;
 private FirebaseAuth auth;
 ConnectionDetector cd;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    MultiDex.install(this);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    cd=new ConnectionDetector(this);
    if(cd.isConnected())
    {
        auth= FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        if(auth.getCurrentUser()!=null)
        {
            //user already signed in
            Log.d("AUTH",auth.getCurrentUser().getEmail());
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"User Already logged in",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else
        {
            startActivityForResult(AuthUI.getInstance()
                    .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                    .setProviders(AuthUI.GOOGLE_PROVIDER,
                            AuthUI.EMAIL_PROVIDER,
                            AuthUI.FACEBOOK_PROVIDER).build(),RC_SIGN_IN);
        }

    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Not Connected to internet",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d("AUTH","No internet connection");
    }

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode==RC_SIGN_IN)
    {
        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK)
        {
            //user logged in
            Log.d("AUTH",auth.getCurrentUser().getEmail());
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"User logged in successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else
        {
            //User not authenticated
            Log.d("AUTH","NOT AUTHENTICATED");
        }
    }
}
}
```

I also tried uses-permission here is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.codehacker.pocketambulance">

<permission
    android:name="com.codehacker.pocketambulance.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />


<uses-permission android:name="com.codehacker.pocketambulance.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!--
         The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
         (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
         Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
         You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
         sign the APK for publishing.
         You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" />
</application>
```

Stacktrace:

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main                    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions
                                                   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
                                                   at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1214)
                                                   at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1189)
                                                   at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4912)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4518)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4458)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:144)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1319)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5136)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: `compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.6.0'` Then Clean-rebuild

Answer (score 0):

You are using

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'
```

If your ui version is `0.4.4` , then play service version should be `9.4.0`

Check [here](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#installation) for the corresponding play and ui service version

Comment: Why are you recommending to downgrade the play services and not upgrading the Firebase dependency?

Comment: Actually , I am not recommending it . I just suggested to make things work based on whatever OP posted . At the same time I also suggested  to use the appropriate version corresponding to version of firebase ui , which is the main of my answer .

Answer (score 0):

Firebase initialization occurs in a `ContentProvider` that is created very early in the app initialization sequence, before your `MainActivity` is created.  You cannot call `Multidex.install()` in your `MainActivity`--that is too late.  The simplest way to initialize Multidex is to specify [MultiDexApplication](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/multidex/MultiDexApplication.html) as your Application class in your manifest.  This is described in the [instructions for configuring Multidex](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#mdex-gradle) and requires addition of a single line in your manifest:

```
android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
```

Also, it is not good practice to include the entire Play Services library in your build:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'
```

This adds *every* Play Services and Firebase API, which increases build time, makes your APK larger, and is possibly the reason you need Multidex.  It is better to include only the libraries for the APIs you actually need.  The full list of APIs is [provided here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) in the section titled *Selectively compiling APIs into your executable*.

Comment: I have done both added android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" and also used multidex.instal(this).. Should i skip one of them or use both in my code

Comment: When `MultiDexApplication` is declared as the application class in the manifest, you do not need to call `Multidex.install()`.

Comment: Thanks qbix it has soveld the query i have declared     MultiDexApplication in the manifest